# Generating fractional Brownian motion in R

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, gaussian-process, brownian-motion

I was trying to generate fractional Brownian motion in R using `fbm` of the package `somebm`. However, in this package, I can not define the time interval on which the data will be generated. So, is there a way to generate fBm in R on a user given time interval?